# MySql code to MySqli (insert with php)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here I write a code to add data to mysql database:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'korisnik', 'pass') or die('Error connecting to server');

mysql_select_db('baza', $con); 

    mysql_select_db('baza', $con);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `stat` (`Name`, `Gender`, `Age`, `Donuts eaten`) VALUES (";
      $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name']) . "', ";
      $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Gender']) . "', ";
      $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Age']) . "', ";
      $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Donuts_eaten']);
      $query .= "')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result != false) {
        echo "Uspesno dodavanje!";
    } else {
        echo "Greska!";
    }

?>
```

How this code will looks like if I use MYSQLi ?

```
<?php


?>
```

and why is MySqli conncetion better that Mysql?

Comment: Is this code is a part of your system or just a start up code because you cannot simply convert mysql to mysqli, there are so many codes that will be affected in your current project.

Comment: http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-mysqli/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and they will be removed in the near future.

You can see the warning message [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

About the code, MySQLi is like MySQL, but offers the option to use prepared statements, some security improvements, and a more abstract way to develop your database layer.

Comment: ok, i will ask google before ask here, sorry, thanks for help

Comment: Is better to use mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @MikiMrki; if you're developing specific, MySQLi can do the job, but PDO is good and well documented and it's recomended and used by many Frameworks and programmers.

Comment: @MikiMrki, I think its just a matter of preference. I prefer mysqli just because I'm a bit more used to it opposed to PDO. As for asking google, the first 30 pages programming related always end up at SO lol

Comment: There's no better option, there's the better option for you. PDO offers a database abstraction layer, then you can work with any database driver you want, MySQLi offers only MySQLi.

In my opinion, you should start with MySQLi, study object oriented programming very much, then you try PDO. :)

Here's a very useful link for you.

http://us.phptherightway.com/

Answer (score 2):

Well your empty code block can look pretty much the same except your connection setting would be param 1 and of course mysql => mysqli. But just doing it that way defeats the purpose of mysqli because your not using it to its full advantages like prepared statements, and parameter binding just to name a couple